# Copy nested Model object to DTO object using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to copy data object to data transfer object which is nested with the same type.

**C#**

```
public class Data
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeInfo { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Data> Data { get; set; }
}

public class DTOData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeInfo { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DTOData> Data { get; set; }
}

List<Data> data = new List<Data>();
data.Add(new Data(){Id =1, SomeInfo  = 'sometext' });

List<DTOData> dtoData = new List<DTOData>();
dtoData.Add(new DTOData(){Id =10, SomeInfo  = 'sometext2' });
```

I want to copy data object to DTOData (data transfer object).

My approach

```
dtoData = (DTOData) data;
```

But it is throwing exception of type mismatch. How can I achive copying the data object to DTOData object, the main complexity with this is that it has nested self referencing. Please help.

Comment: You'll have to iterate over each object and manually make a new object for each copy assign each property individually.

Comment: vish, it is a dynamic object and we do not know how deep the nested object is. By nested I mean the icollection of Data. That is my issue.

Comment: then you can make the DTO data dynamic as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't care about performance this could be a solution, serialize and deserialize it to the new type using json and newtonsoft, something like:

```
dtoData  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DTOData>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
```

in the case of a list object:

```
dtoData  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DTOData>>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
```

Comment: It effects the performance. The performance is very slow.

Comment: @Pearl yes sir, that's the first thing i said, that's only for scenarios where low performance is not an issue.

Comment: @Pearl you could try using reflection , here is a nice article about it: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/property-copying-between-two-objects-using-reflection

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly transform each `Data` object into a new `DTOData` object one way or another.

You could for example do this iteratively using a `Stack<T>`. Something like this:

```
static List<DTOData> Map(List<Data> data)
{
    if (data == null)
        return null;

    var dtos = new List<DTOData>(data.Count);
    var stack = new Stack<(Data source, DTOData parent)>();
    foreach (var root in data)
    {
        //store the root nodes in the list to be returned
        var dto = new DTOData() { Id = root.Id, SomeInfo = root.SomeInfo };
        dtos.Add(dto);

        if (root.Data != null)
        {
            dto.Data = new List<DTOData>(root.Data.Count);
            foreach (var child in root.Data)
                stack.Push((child, dto));
        }

        //handle the child nodes
        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            var x = stack.Pop();
            dto = new DTOData() { Id = x.source.Id, SomeInfo = x.source.SomeInfo };

            if (x.parent != null)
                x.parent.Data.Add(dto);

            if (x.source.Data != null)
            {
                dto.Data = new List<DTOData>(x.source.Data.Count);
                foreach (var child in x.source.Data)
                    stack.Push((child, dto));
            }
        }
    }
    return dtos;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use LINQ and query the original list to the new list.

```
List<DTOData> dtoData = data
    .Select(x => new DTOData(){Id =x.Id, SomeInfo  = x.SomeInfo })
    .ToList();
```

Here's a console app that shows better.

```
using SelectMany;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

var listOfAs = new List<A>
{
    new (new B[] { new (1, 2), new (3, 4) }),
    new (new B[] { new (5, 6), new (7, 8) })
};

var listOfDtos = listOfAs
    .SelectMany(a => a.Bs)
    .Select(b => new Dto(b.BCount1 + b.BCount2))
    .ToList();

foreach (var dto in listOfDtos) Console.WriteLine(dto.TotalCount);

namespace SelectMany
{
    public record A(IEnumerable<B> Bs);
    public record B(int BCount1, int BCount2);
    public record Dto(int TotalCount);
}

//output:
//3
//7
//11
//15
```

Comment: Yes, how to iterate n level nested list of data?

Comment: For nested types you can do the same but use SelectMany()...

Comment: @Pearl I've updated the answer to hopefully help.

Comment: I'm not sure how it's getting marked down.  Did I miss something about the question?